# What is the correct HTML table markup for this example?

Tags: html, html-table

An accountancy package, which I am converting to a web app, often has table constructs like the following:

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| DATE           | ACCOUNT        |    BALANCE |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 13/06/2011     | Account One    |      10.00 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 13/06/2011     | Account Two    |      10.00 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 13/06/2011     | Account Three  |      10.00 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
|                |          TOTAL |      30.00 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

The problem is the last row. TOTAL clearly has no relationship with the column header, ACCOUNT. Would it be OK if the TOTAL cell is a TH with scope="row"? Should it also span all the columns to its left? Is this a job for TFOOT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for a combination of the `th scope="row"` and putting the `<tfoot>` element just after the `<thead>`. You *might* also want to put in the `headers` attribute on each `<td>` but for such a small table it's arguable.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="h-date">Date</th>
            <th id="h-account">Account</th>
            <th id="h-balance">Balance</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" colspan="2">TOTAL</th>
            <td headers="h-balance">30.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td headers="h-date">13/06/2011</td>
            <td headers="h-account">Account One</td>
            <td headers="h-balance">10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="h-date">13/06/2011</td>
            <td headers="h-account">Account Two</td>
            <td headers="h-balance">10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="h-date">13/06/2011</td>
            <td headers="h-account">Account Three</td>
            <td headers="h-balance">10.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This would definitely be what I'd suggest. If you're in a microformats mood, you might want to mark up the dates better too — allowing for ISO 8601[1] formatting, like `2011-06-13`.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Incidentally, why is it beater to have the `tfoot` before the `tbody`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right lines. I'd use a table footer with two cells. The first would be a `<th colspan="2">` and the second a regular `<td>`.

(Edit: A previous version of this answer referred to `rowspan` rather than `colspan`).

Comment: How necessary is the `rowspan`? In this app, it's quite possible that users may select and copy the table to paste into Excel. How well does Excel cope with rowspans?

Comment: I don't know how Excel copes with rowspans - but it should be easy to test. I don't think the rowspan in itself is particularly important, so if it messes up copying to Excel then don't use it. Real world usability trumps HTML semantics.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Excel "does the right thing" with the colspan (not rowspan here; I assume that's a typo) — and created a "merged cell", to reproduce what the HTML had.

Comment: err... yes, colspan not rowspan. More a brain-fart than a typo, I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>13/06/2011</td>
            <td>Account One</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13/06/2011</td>
            <td>Account Two</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13/06/2011</td>
            <td>Account Three</td>
            <td>10.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td>30.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't TOTAL be a TH though?